# Воспользоваться функцией из другого cpp/h файла

Tags: c++

Подскажите как объявить, и в последующем обратиться к функции в другом файле

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Во-первых,* в `.h`-файлах нет никаких функций. Это просто кусок текста, вставляемый перед компиляцией вместо соответствующих директив `#include`. Соответственно, с точки зрения компилятора нет никакой разницы, включили ли вы заголовочный файл или просто взяли и скопировали его содержимое в свой `.cpp` руками.

**То есть для решения вашей задачи нет разницы между заголовочным файлом с объявлением функции:**

> - *decl.h*:
>
>   ```
>   #pragma once
>   void foo(int bar);
>   ```
> - *main.cpp*:
>
>   ```
>   #include "decl.h"
>   int main()
>   {
>       foo(21); // Использование функции
>   }
>   ```
> - *implementation.cpp*:
>
>   ```
>   #include "decl.h"
>   void foo(int bar)
>   {
>      // Реализация функции
>   }
>   ```

**и повтором объявления в каждом `.cpp`-файле, которому нужна эта функция:**

> - *main.cpp*:
>
>   ```
>   void foo(int bar);
>   int main()
>   {
>       foo(21); // Использование функции
>   }
>   ```
> - *implementation.cpp*:
>
>   ```
>   void foo(int bar)
>   {
>      // Реализация функции
>   }
>   ```

*Во-вторых,* `.cpp`-файл — это «вещь в себе», чёрный ящик с двоичными данными и списком того, что этот ящик импортирует/экспортирует, и по каким байтовым смещениям в вышеуказанных данных это требуется/реализуется соответственно:

1. Если в `.cpp`-файле производится обращение к чему-то, нереализованному в этом файле, и у компилятора есть объявление (то есть прототип для проверки корректности обращения), генерируется импорт этого чего-то по имени.
2. Если в `.cpp`-файле объявляется не-`static` переменная либо функция (методы классов, кстати, тоже полноценные функции), генерируется экспорт.

И только потом, на этапе компоновки производится связывание соответствующих импортов и экспортов этих «чёрных ящиков» (а также подобных «ящиков», составляющих реализацию стандартной библиотеки).

Answer (score 2):

Общий принцип - объявление (`void sort_mass(int*, int);`) должно быть доступно в момент использования для успешной компиляции (поэтому их обычно располагают в заголовочных файлах, включаемых в другие файлы.

Определение (тело функции) необходимо во время компоновки, и должно быть (если это не inline или static функция) единственным в программе. Поэтому, если оно находится в отдельном файле, этот файл должен быть скомпилирован и скомпонован с основной программой (включен в проект).

Такой файл может включаться в уже скомпилированном виде (как объектный файл или в составе библиотеки).

Comment: Вы вызываете ее не "оттуда". Вызывается код функции, до компоновки находящийся в другом файле. А чтобы компилятор мог это сделать, ему нужно знать, что такая функция - с данным именем и параметрами - существует. Это как бы обещание :) - мол, вызывай, не бойся - компоновщик найдет, что именно вызывать.